# Can some one help in setting up ReactFlow

Tags: reactjs

Error description:

```
Uncaught Error: The React Flow parent container needs a width and a height to render the graph.
updateDimensions 0.chunk.js:42077
GraphView 0.chunk.js:42085
React 6
unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:653
React 3
workLoop scheduler.development.js:597
flushWork scheduler.development.js:552
performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:164
```

All suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Please read [ask] to learn how to improve your question.

Comment: Not familiar with this library, but according to the code examples they have in their docs, you have to add a style prop with width and height to the ReactFlow component, e.g. style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}

Answer (score 3):

you can add
style={{ height: 500 }} in your div, it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It gets not rendered because the parent has no width or height. Try to set an explicit width and height for the parent container to check if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add extra div with `style={{height:700}}` and enclose with this `div` remaining `React` flow content

For example

```js
    <div style={{height:700}}>
       <ReactFlow
        nodes={nodes}
        edges={edges}
        onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
        onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
        nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
        fitView
       >
        <Background />
       </ReactFlow>
    </div>
```